# how to get an element with same name in a list to avoid for loop in R

Tags: r, list, sapply

I have a simple question. Assuming I have a list Obj of length 500

```
Obj[[1]], Obj[[2]], ....Obj[[500]], #for each Obj[[i]], it has an element 
Obj[[i]]$logL,
```

My question is how to extract logL of each Obj to avoid a for loop like this?

```
logL = rep(NA, length(Obj))
for(i in 1: length(Obj)){
   logL[i] = Obj[[i]]$logL
}
```

Is there any way to do this with sapply or some advanced packages like plyr? I am open to solutions as long as it is faster than a for loop since I need to do this within MCMC and the length of the list can be 3000 so that I prefer some fast method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you just need to make it a vector? If yes, try unlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use apply group of functions for this purpose. here is a tutorial
http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-apply-sapply-lapply-in-r/

```
sapply(obj, function(x) x$logL )
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this, but got the below error "Error in x$logL : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Comment: try `sapply(obj, function(x) x["logL"] )` If your for loop is working, the above code should work. can u post output of `class(obj[[1]])`?

Comment: Thanks Koundy, yes, they both work! The previous case I only create Obj$logL, it does not work, later I create Obj[[1]]$logL, Obj[[2]]$logL, the two methods you recommend both work! Thanks a lot, it is very helpful!

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to make it into a vector, this should do it. No need of an apply.

```
unlist(Obj)
```

Comment: I see, this is a simple and efficient method! Thanks very much!:)